# 500 Internal Server Error Trying to Send an SMS using Twilio

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, twilio

Using Heroku to host a Sinatra app. I have a route that's supposed to send an SMS. It returns a 500 internal server error instead.

Everything works perfectly fine in localhost. The logs show a Twilio::REST::RequestError.

**main.rb**

```
post '/sms/send' do

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

    @client.account.messages.create(
        from: '+xxxxxxxxxxx',
        to: '+xxxxxxxxxxx',
        body: 'Robot invasion! Reply back with any sightings.'
    )       
end
```

Logs:

```
2017-05-17T19:04:24.640120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/sms/send" host=dysfunctionalapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a3736f1a-2264-4b91-b0a9-a3bde94342bd fwd="216.73.77.194" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=255 protocol=https
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639060+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-05-17 19:04:24 - Twilio::REST::RequestError - Twilio::REST::RequestError:
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639072+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/twilio-ruby-4.13.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/base_client.rb:125:in `connect_and_send'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639074+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/twilio-ruby-4.13.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/base_client.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <class:BaseClient>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639075+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/twilio-ruby-4.13.0/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb:94:in `create'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639076+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/main.rb:84:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639078+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1632:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639078+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1632:in `block in compile!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639079+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:991:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639095+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1010:in `route_eval'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639096+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:991:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639097+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1037:in `block in process_route'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639097+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1035:in `catch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639098+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1035:in `process_route'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639099+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:989:in `block in route!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639099+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:988:in `each'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639100+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:988:in `route!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639101+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1094:in `block in dispatch!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639101+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `block in invoke'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639102+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `catch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639102+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `invoke'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639103+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1091:in `dispatch!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639104+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:923:in `block in call!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639105+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `block in invoke'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639105+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `catch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639106+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `invoke'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639106+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:923:in `call!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639107+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:913:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639108+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639108+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639109+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:26:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639110+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639110+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:50:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639111+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-protection-2.0.0/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639112+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639113+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/common_logger.rb:33:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639113+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:231:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639114+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:224:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639114+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639115+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639116+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:194:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639116+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1955:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639117+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1499:in `block in call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639118+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1726:in `synchronize'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639118+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1499:in `call'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639125+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639125+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639126+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639127+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639127+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639129+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639130+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639130+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639131+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639132+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639133+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639133+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639134+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639135+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/thin:22:in `load'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639137+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639136+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/thin:22:in `<top (required)>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639138+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639139+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639140+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639138+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639140+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639141+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639142+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639144+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639144+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639145+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639146+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639146+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639147+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
2017-05-17T19:04:24.639551+00:00 app[web.1]: 216.73.77.194 - - [17/May/2017:19:04:24 +0000] "POST /sms/send HTTP/1.1" 500 30 0.0217
```

I'm kind of lost. I apologize for the vagueness. Where should I start?

Comment: I first suggest, you should write code that handle Exception. Please check their document for exception handling. https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby#exceptions

Comment: I did that, copying and pasting in and changing the phone numbers. It got rid of the 500 internal error, but nothing sends. And checking Heroku logs, there's no additional messages.

Comment: ok. Locally application runs in development environment and when we deploy on Heroku, it runs on production environment. Did you checked both environment configuration for twilio ? Also please update your question and add code for exception handling.

Comment: That was it. I was using  ENV[] for the Twilio SID and auth token. How would I reference those environment variables in a production environment?

Comment: I am going to write answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion in comment, you have configuration problem. You can run program in locally(development environment) and not heroku(production environment).

As you mention in comment, you are using EVN to set credentials. You can do set this in 2 ways to set ENV in Heroku.

1) write configuration in `config/production.rb`

2) **Recommended** : Set ENV from Heroku Console. Here is Ref. link to do it [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

You can also use [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for your application.

Hope that helps !